# Trouble with moving entity

Tags: actionscript-3

I am currently trying to get acclimated to FlashDevelop, but am having trouble moving an entity, despite following tutorials very closely.

```
public class Main extends Engine 
{
    private var gameWorld:MyWorld;
    public function Main() 
    {
        super(800, 600, 60, false);
        gameWorld = new MyWorld;
    }

    override public function init():void
    {
        FP.world = gameWorld;
        trace("FlashPunk has started successfully!");
    }

}

public class MyWorld extends World
{
    private var gameEntity:MyEntity;
    public function MyWorld()
    {
        gameEntity = new MyEntity();
        add(gameEntity);

    }

    override public function update():void
    {
        //trace("MyEntity updates");

    }
}

public class MyEntity extends Entity
{
    [Embed(source = "dragon.png")] private const PLAYER:Class;

    public function MyEntity() 
    {
            name = "player";
            graphic = new Image(PLAYER);


    }

    override public function update():void
    {
        x += 10;
        y += 5;

        //if (Input.check(Key.LEFT)) { x -= 5; }
        //if (Input.check(Key.RIGHT)) { x += 5; }
        //if (Input.check(Key.UP)) { y -= 5; }
        //if (Input.check(Key.DOWN)) { y += 5; }
    }

    override public function added():void
    {
        trace("Entity added");
    }

}
```

It is supposed to move across the screen, but does not for some reason. Any thoughts?

Comment: In the code you provided nothing calls your entity `update()`

Comment: Thanks, how would I go about doing that? Sorry, complete newb.

Comment: That really depends on how you want your update function to run. If you want it to run every frame then it should be tied to an Event.ENTER_FRAME, as in `addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, runUpdates)` then you create a function `runUpdates(e:Event)` and inside it would call `gameEntity.update()`. I'm assuming since you're using flash punk there might be some automated process for calling update functions, I personally don't know as I don't use that engine.

Comment: I added super.update() to my MyWorld class, and it works. Thanks for the help.